# Inserting in a table that has a column in another table

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a project created in java (using NetBeans) for inserting data in  table `A` in MySQL.

Table A has a primary key pID and it has 11 columns, but table `A` has to a column that is foreign key of table `B`. When I try to insert a row in table `A` in MySQL it works.The row is inserted.

But, when I try to insert a row in java (using a procedure `usp_em` that I created in MySQL; it does not involve autoincremented columns) it does not work.
I make the call of procedure in this way:

```
  CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("call usp_em(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
```

So I do not understand why I can insert a row directly in MySQL,but not from java? The MySQL JDBC driver is used as a library too!

Comment: can you share your code please?

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your procedure between `{}` for example :

```
String query = "{call usp_em(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}"; 
//--------------^------------------------------^
CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall(query);  
statement.setString(1, param1);
statement.setString(2, param2);
statement.setString(3, param3);
...  
statement.execute();
```